How to get registered routes in server middleware with SSR
My Nuxt3 App structure is like this.
pages
┣ ab
┃　┣ 028
┃　┃　┣ [id].vue
┃　┃　┗ index.vue
┃　┗　　029
┃  ┣ index.vue
┃  ┗ ranking
┃    ┗ index.vue
┣　index.vue
┣ [id].vue
┗ ranking
  ┣ index.vue
  ┗ [slug].vue
server
┗ middleware
  ┗ redirects.js


To redirect correct page, I need to get registerd routes in server/middleware/redirect.js.
It would be better if I colud get bellow array.
const availableRoutes = [
'/',
'/:id',
'/ranking',
'/ranking/:slug',
'/ab/028',
'/ab/028/:id',
'/ab/029/',
'/ab/029/ranking'
]

How do I get available routes?

You can use:
useRouter().getRoutes().map(r => r.path)

Docs: https://router.vuejs.org/api/interfaces/Router.html#getRoutes
